# How to Delete Authentication Cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, session-cookies

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application. I made some changes to save some extra info in cookie in latest version.
Few of my customers are still running old version.
Is there any way to expire the existing cookies of my existing customer and enforce them to log-on again when they connect to my new application hosted in IIS?

Thanks,

Comment: just set the date for cookie to some already went-by date....it shall ensure that user logs in again

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use the [SignOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) static method:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

This will remove the authentication cookie and on **subsequent** requests the user will not be authenticated. I stressed the word subsequent because after calling this method you should redirect.

Comment: where should i put this line. I m afraid, wherever i will put this line, it will force user to logon every time...

Comment: @SutikshanDubey, you put this line in some controller action from which you want to sign the current user out when he navigates to it.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me, but it put me on the trail. I had rebuilt aspnetdb, but there was still a FormsAuthenticationCookie in the browser. I was then in the catch-22 of an Request.Authenticated==true, but GetUser() returns null; thus, no user to log out. Solution was to remove all the cookies on the browser.

Answer (score 4):

I am giving newer name to my cookie in web.config, and this seem to solve my problem:-

```
 <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" name="InsightWebMobileCookie2" timeout="10000" slidingExpiration="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you cannot read the cookie expiration date so you don't know from the cookie who the old users are.

So your options are:

1. If you can figure out who is from the 'old' version - have logic to expire their cookie.
2. Force everyone to logout once if they dont have a cookie named "VersionLogout". Once you force their logout, set a cookie named "VersionLogout" with a value of 1.2 for example, this way you know you've forced their logout for a particular version and they  (going forward) won't be prompted again.

You would put that code in a Application_AuthenticateRequest event in the global.asax. at this point a user has been authenticated so you can check  their cookie there.